# Check for empty lines and remove them/move the lines below it up

Tags: python, list, file

I have been looking for a solution to a problem I have for a while now, but to no avail.

I have the following function:

```
def showEmail():
    f = open("players.txt","r") 
    for line in f:
        lineList = line.split(";") 
        print "Name: " + lineList[0] + " " + lineList[1]
        print "Email address: " + lineList[2]
        print ""
    f.close()
```

My file has text as shown:

```
Sam;Tyler;s.tyler@gmail.com;0710503687;6;0
Peter;Bond;p.bond@gmail.com;0798415758;6;0
Joe;Blogg;j.bloggs@gmail.com;0749814574;1;60
```

The issue arises when an empty line inevitably appears in my file (when modifying a line, the program will create a new line similar to the one modified and change the value of that line. It then deletes the original line, and copies the new one, thus the empty line, and copies it all to a new document). This is done as shown. :

```
def writeToFile(): #function to write all new (modified) lines from players to a temps file, deletes players and rename temps to 'players'
    f = open("players.txt",'r') # Input file
    t = open("temp.txt", 'w') #Temp output file

    for line in f:
        if line != originalInfo: #doesn't write the line that is the same as the original info
            t.write(line) #writes all lines apart from the original line (one that needs to be deleted)

    f.close()
    t.close()
    os.remove("players.txt") #deletes players
    os.rename('temp.txt', 'players.txt') #new file with modified info is renamed to players
```

If the file contains the following, the program will tell me that the list index is out of bound, which makes sense because it considers the empty line as a list.

```
Sam;Tyler;s.tyler@gmail.com;0710503687;6;0
Peter;Bond;p.bond@gmail.com;0798415758;6;0

Joe;Blogg;j.bloggs@gmail.com;0749814574;1;60
```

How can I remedy to this issue? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not clear on why the file-writing portion `for line in f:...` would be creating blank lines. If the input file doesn't have any lines that consist solely of `'\n'`, none should appear in the output.

Comment: Which problem do you want to solve : the write subroutine should'nt write blank lines or the read subroutine should be able to deal with blank lines ?

Comment: I've had to populated the file with `fullName = forename + ";" + surname + ";" + email + ";" + phone + ";" + division + ";" + points + "\n"` because without it adding two player in a row will juxtapose them, not add them on a separate line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've modified and possibly cleared a line, you should just check if the line is empty before writing it:

```
def writeToFile():
    ...
    for line in f:
        if line != originalInfo and line != "\n" # or whatever you're using for an empty line
             t.write(line)
    ...
```

Comment: `and line.strip()` is a popular idiom to use here.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is formated like a CSV file, so what about using csv module offered by Python, look at the exemple below:

```
import csv

def showEmail():
    with open("player.txt","r") as f:
        csvFile = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
        for line in csvFile:
            if line:
                print("Name: {} {}".format(line[0], line[1]))
                print("Email address: {}".format(line[2]))
                print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this better:

```
with open(file) as f_in:
    return filter(None, (line.rstrip() for line in f_in))
```